# Incrementing Value of incoming value in Azure Table Insert

Tags: ios, node.js, azure, azure-mobile-services

I am an iOS developer & currently working with Azure mobile services SDK in iOS.

In my case, I am providing each user as a uniqueid say 'myid' in Table say 'todomytable'. In  todomytable.js file I am performing check for myid value. If coming value of 'myid' from device is less than stored value in table then I am increasing incoming value greater than earlier stored value in table by One.  Below is my logic in todomytable.js

```
    table.insert(function (context) {

          context.item.userId = context.user.id;
          //....
        var intIncomingID = context.item.myid; //ID coming from mobile device
        //Call back to get max value of 'myid' from Table
        var myFunction =  function( callback) {
                 var query = {
                    sql: 'select MAX(myid) from TodoItem'
                 };
                context.data.execute(query).then(function (results) {
                var objectTest = eval(JSON.stringify(results));
                var tempObject = objectTest[0];
                var previuosIntID = tempObject["MAX(myid)"];
                callback(previuosIntID);
             });
          };


          myFunction(function(returnValue) {
              console.log("returnValue is : "+returnValue);
            if (intIncomingID<=returnValue)
            {
              console.log('IF');
              context.item.userId = context.user.id;
              returnValue = returnValue+1;
              context.item.myid = returnValue;
              console.log("UPDATED value is : "+context.item.myid);
            }
            else{
               context.item.myid = intIncomingID;
               console.log("ITEM value is :"+intIncomingID);
            }
           return context.execute();
         });
});
```

But issue is that table is not getting update & in mobile log I am getting network request time out error as below

```
{Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1001 "The request timed out."}
```

Can anyone suggest how to resolve this issue? I have to store 'myid' in incremented order in table. I am new to Node.js, so sorry If I am making any foolish mistake.

Comment: Please add the initialization routine of the MobileServiceClient to your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is likely that there is an exception occurring at some point that causes a promise to reject. Given that there is no promise exception handler defined, the exception ends up being "swallowed". Try the following:

```
var table = module.exports = require('azure-mobile-apps').table()

table.insert(function (context) {
  context.item.userId = context.user.id;

  var intIncomingID = context.item.myid; //ID coming from mobile device
  var query = { sql: 'select MAX(myid) from TodoItem' };

  return context.data.execute(query)
    .then(function (results) {
      var tempObject = results[0];
      var previousIntID = tempObject["MAX(myid)"];

      console.log("previous ID is : " + previousIntID);

      if (intIncomingID <= previousIntID) {
        context.item.myid = previousIntID + 1;
        console.log("UPDATED value is : " + context.item.myid);
      } else {
        context.item.myid = intIncomingID;
        console.log("ITEM value is :" + intIncomingID);
      }

      return context.execute();
    });
});
```

Some points to note:

- `context.data.execute` returns a promise - we are returning this from the `insert` function so that the Mobile Apps runtime handles any rejected promises
- `context.execute` also returns a promise; we are returning this so that the promises are "chained" properly

Hope this helps!